# how to do a dependancy injection with a method in micronaut for unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, micronaut

I have a controller class:

```
@Controller("/x")
class Controller {

@Get
fun index(): String {
    return "test test"
}

@Post
fun dopost (userid) = executelogin(login.userId)
}
```

This controller depends on the executelogin method down below:

```
fun executelogin(userid) =
   do things
```

If I want to write a unit test, how would I go about using a dependancy injection to introduce a version of the executelogin method. Below is what I have so far and I am not sure if I am doing it correctly:

```
@MicronautTest
class Controllertest(val method: executelogin()) {



@Inject
    lateinit var client: RxHttpClient


@Test
fun testController(){
    val request: HttpRequest<String> = HttpRequest.POST("/hello","test")
    val body: String = client.toBlocking().retrieve(request)

    assertNotNull(body)
    assertEquals(method,method)
    
}
}
```

Above in the unit test, I am making the executelogin method a paramter for the controllertest class, which I believe is called a method injection. I was wondering if this was the correct way to go about this or if adjustments need to be made. I apologise if some of the code does not quite make sense, I am new to micronaut and the concept of dependancy injections.

Answer (score 1):

> If I want to write a unit test, how would I go about using a
> dependancy injection to introduce a version of the executelogin
> method.

You can't go about using dependency injection to introduce a version fo the `executelogin` method, at least not directly you can't.  Micronaut doesn't support method injection.

This isn't what you asked but just as an FYI... A common thing to do would be to inject some object that contains the method that you want to call.